# AJAX Combobox Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm utilizing the AJAX combobox on my web page.  The page also uses a tab control that contains about 5 different tab pages. The combobox is located on the first tab and is inside an UpdatePanel. On one of the other tab pages I have a custom calendar control that is also inside an UpdatePanel. The calendar was working fine until I added the AJAX combobox on the first tab page. When adding items to the calendar it is setup to automatically refresh its data.

However, now when I add an item to the calendar, the refresh (which causes a partial postback for the Calendar's UpdatePanel) just hangs and never completes. The data is stored in the database, but the calendar never refreshes.  This appears to be directly related to the AJAX combobox on the first tab page. I get an error in my event log:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: FormatException 
Exception message: Input string was not in a correct format.
Stack trace:    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
at AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
at AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Has anyone seen this before or know how to resolve? I wouldn't expect the combobox to be trying to reload data since it was not in the same UpdatePanel as the Calendar (it has its own UpdatePanel) because it should only be doing a partial postback.

Am I missing something here? Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual PostBack data here? Grab it with something like Fiddler or firebug. Also, is localization, CultureInfo properly set to the same all the time? That can cause problems with number, or datetime parsing. And another idea: some required fields are not filled properly during the partial PostBack, and that causes the exception.

Comment: What exactly do you want to see from the PostBack data? Using fiddler so I'm not sure what all to copy. Also, CultureInfo is set only once throughout the project, and it happens to be on the population of dates ranges to select when adding a calendar item(set to en-us).

Answer (score 0):

What I can suspect here is, you have not set the UpdateMode property of your update panel that contains your ComboBox and so it is getting updated everytime your calendar Update panel gets updated because by default the UpdateMode has value "Always".

So in my opinion you have to set your ComboBox update panel property like this

```
UpdateMode="Conditional"
```

and then you have to do either of the two things depending on your requirement

1. Set update panel's property

   ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
2. Explicitly call update panel's "Update" method from your code after all your processing.

   Tab1UpdatePanel.Update();

Comment: Update mode was set to conditional for all UpdatePanels. There appears to be a bug in the AJAX combobox so we just came up with a different solution.